# Why is my context disposed before I can use it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hotchocolate

I'm implementing a very simple query using the `HotChocolate` GraphQL library in a .Net 5 project. I've been following the [tutorial series](https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-workshop/blob/master/docs/1-creating-a-graphql-server-project.md) from the HotChocolate GitHub repository but in my project I don't want GraphQL accessing the context directly and would instead prefer for it to access a repository that manages database access via the context.

I've built a few REST endpoints in this project alongside GraphQL and this repository pattern works properly there. However when I call these repository methods from a GraphQL, the context is disposed before the repository method uses it.

I am guessing that the way HotChocolate uses the context causes it to get disposed earlier than I am expecting, but I am having trouble figuring out when/where it gets disposed and how I can prevent it from being disposed so my repository methods will work.

**ContentRepository.cs**

```c#
namespace BLL.Repository
{
    public class ContentRepository : IRepository<Content>
    {
        private readonly CmsContext _dbContext;

        public ContentRepository(CmsContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public virtual List<Content> GetContent()
        {
            return _dbContext.Content.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**Query.cs**

```c#
namespace Web.GraphQL
{
    public class Query
    {
        private readonly IContentRepository _contentRepository;

        public Query(IContentRepository contentRepository)
        {
            _contentRepository = contentRepository;
        }
        
        public List<Content> GetContent()
        {
            return _contentRepository.GetContent() as List<Content>;
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```c#
namespace Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            
            services.AddDbContext<CmsContext>(options =>
                options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), ServerVersion.AutoDetect(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))));
            
            services
                .AddGraphQLServer()
                .ModifyRequestOptions(options => options.IncludeExceptionDetails = true)
                .AddQueryType<Query>();

            services.AddScoped<IRepository<Content>, ContentRepository>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "/{controller}/{action}",
                    new {controller = "Default", action = "Index"});
            });

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapGraphQL());

            app.UseGraphQLVoyager(new VoyagerOptions
            {
                GraphQLEndPoint = "/graphql"
            }, "/graphql-voyager");
        }
    }
}
```

When debugging and stepping through the code, once it has reached the `GetContent` method in `ContentRepository.cs` it throws an `ObjectDisposedException`.

What do I need to do to ensure that `CmsContext` is still available to the `ContentRepository` when called from a GraphQL query?

Comment: Don't use constructor injection, use parameter injection with `[Service]` attribute. https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/blob/develop/templates/StarWars/content/Characters/CharacterQueries.cs#L34-L36

Comment: And how do you even get to ContentRepository in the first place? Also, those repository/query classes are overly complex and provide no benefit whatsoever. Besides that, Query knows an implementation detail from the repository which it shouldn't know (the cast to `List<T>`)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I agree on the unnecessary abstraction of the DbContext, but `IList`/`ICollection`/`IReadonlyList` vs `List` isn't too bad.

Comment: @abdusco Oops, ignore the last point, I saw the cast and immediately thought of `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>` (which I've seen too often)

Comment: You are trying to read from the context before you context is filled with data.  I thik you missed following step : services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=conferences.db"));

Comment: @abdusco that solved my problem. If you make it an answer I will accept it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use constructor injection [with HotChocolate **v11**](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/api-reference/dependency-injection):

```cs
services
    .AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>()
    .AddScoped<Query>()
    .AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddQueryType<Query>()

public class Query
{
    public Query(IUserRepository repository)
    {

    }

    // code omitted for brevity
}
```

If you're on HotChocolate **v10**, you need to [use parameter injection](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v10/server/dependency-injection) with `[Service]`  attribute:

```cs
public class Query
{
    public string Bar(ISchema schema, [Service]MyCustomService service)
    {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

### References

- https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v10/server/dependency-injection
- https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/api-reference/dependency-injection

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, in the constructor you can also get the service like this:

```
public class Query
    {
        private readonly IEntityRepository _entityRepository;
  
        public Query([Service] IEntityRepository entityRepository)  
        {  
            _entityRepository= entityRepository;  
        }
  
        public IQueryable<Entity> Entities=> _entityRepository.GetAll();
    }
```